# Stuck in a loop / bad Xpath when doing scraping of website

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape data from this website: https://aa-dc.org/meetings?tsml-day=any&tsml-type=IPM

I have made the following script for the intial data:

```
import scrapy


class WaiascrapSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'waiascrap'
    allowed_domains = ['clsaa-dc.org']
    start_urls = ['https://aa-dc.org/meetings?tsml-day=any&tsml-type=IPM']

    def parse(self, response):
        rows = response.xpath("//tr")
        for row in rows:
            day = rows.xpath("(//tr/td[@class='time']/span)[1]/text()").get()
            time = rows.xpath("//tr/td[@class='time']/span/time/text()").get()

            yield{
                'day': day,
                'time': time,
            }
```

however the data I'm getting is repeated, like if I'm not navigating the For cycle:

> PS C:\Users\gasgu\PycharmProjects\ScrapingProject\projects\waia>
> scrapy crawl waiascrap 2021-08-20 15:25:11 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO:
> Scrapy 2.5.0 started (bot: waia) 2021-08-20 15:25:11
> [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.6.3.0, libxml2 2.9.5,
> cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 21.7.0, Python
> 3.9.6 (t ags/v3.9.6:db3ff76, Jun 28 2021, 15:26:21) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 20.0.1 (OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021), cryptography
> 3.4.7, Platform Windows-10-
> 10.0.19042-SP0 2021-08-20 15:25:11 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor 2021-08-20
> 15:25:11 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME':
> 'waia',  'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'waia.spiders',  'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
> 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['waia.spiders']} 2021-08-20 15:25:11
> [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 9299b6be5840b21c
> 2021-08-20 15:25:11 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
> ['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
> 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
> 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats'] 2021-08-20 15:25:11
> [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
> ['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats'] 2021-08-20
> 15:25:11 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
> ['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware'] 2021-08-20 15:25:11
> [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: [] 2021-08-20
> 15:25:11 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened 2021-08-20 15:25:11
> [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min),
> scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min) 2021-08-20 15:25:11
> [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on
> 127.0.0.1:6023 2021-08-20 15:25:12 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET [https://aa-dc.org/robots.txt>](https://aa-dc.org/robots.txt%3E) (referer: None) 2021-08-20
> 15:25:13 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET
> [https://aa-dc.org/meetings?tsml-day=any&tsml-type=IPM>](https://aa-dc.org/meetings?tsml-day=any&tsml-type=IPM%3E) (referer: None)
> 2021-08-20 15:25:16 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200
> [https://aa-dc.org/meetings?tsml-day=any&tsml-type=IPM>](https://aa-dc.org/meetings?tsml-day=any&tsml-type=IPM%3E) {'day':
> 'Sunday', 'time': '6:45 am'} 2021-08-20 15:25:19 [scrapy.core.scraper]
> DEBUG: Scraped from <200
> [https://aa-dc.org/meetings?tsml-day=any&tsml-type=IPM>](https://aa-dc.org/meetings?tsml-day=any&tsml-type=IPM%3E) {'day':
> 'Sunday', 'time': '6:45 am'} 2021-08-20 15:25:22 [scrapy.core.scraper]
> DEBUG: Scraped from <200
> [https://aa-dc.org/meetings?tsml-day=any&tsml-type=IPM>](https://aa-dc.org/meetings?tsml-day=any&tsml-type=IPM%3E) {'day':
> 'Sunday', 'time': '6:45 am'} 2021-08-20 15:25:26 [scrapy.core.scraper]
> DEBUG: Scraped from <200
> [https://aa-dc.org/meetings?tsml-day=any&tsml-type=IPM>](https://aa-dc.org/meetings?tsml-day=any&tsml-type=IPM%3E) {'day':
> 'Sunday', 'time': '6:45 am'} 2021-08-20 15:25:29 [scrapy.core.scraper]
> DEBUG: Scraped from <200
> [https://aa-dc.org/meetings?tsml-day=any&tsml-type=IPM>](https://aa-dc.org/meetings?tsml-day=any&tsml-type=IPM%3E) {'day':
> 'Sunday', 'time': '6:45 am'} 2021-08-20 15:25:32 [scrapy.core.scraper]
> DEBUG: Scraped from <200
> [https://aa-dc.org/meetings?tsml-day=any&tsml-type=IPM>](https://aa-dc.org/meetings?tsml-day=any&tsml-type=IPM%3E) {'day':
> 'Sunday', 'time': '6:45 am'} 2021-08-20 15:25:35 [scrapy.core.scraper]
> DEBUG: Scraped from <200
> [https://aa-dc.org/meetings?tsml-day=any&tsml-type=IPM>](https://aa-dc.org/meetings?tsml-day=any&tsml-type=IPM%3E) {'day':
> 'Sunday', 'time': '6:45 am'} 2021-08-20 15:25:39 [scrapy.core.scraper]
> DEBUG: Scraped from <200
> [https://aa-dc.org/meetings?tsml-day=any&tsml-type=IPM>](https://aa-dc.org/meetings?tsml-day=any&tsml-type=IPM%3E) {'day':
> 'Sunday', 'time': '6:45 am'}

EDIT:

now it's working, there was a combination of the errors marked by @Prophet, and a problem with my Xpath.

I'm putting my code working below:

```
import scrapy


class WaiascrapSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'waiascrap'
    allowed_domains = ['clsaa-dc.org']
    start_urls = ['https://aa-dc.org/meetings?tsml-day=any&tsml-type=IPM']

    def parse(self, response):
        rows = response.xpath("//tr")
        for row in rows:
            day = row.xpath(".//td[@class='time']/span/text()").get()
            time = row.xpath(".//td[@class='time']/span/time/text()").get()
            yield {
                'day': day,
                'time': time,
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select element inside element you have to put a dot `.` in front of the XPath expression saying "from here".
Otherwise it will bring you the first match of `(//tr/td[@class='time']/span)[1]/text()` on the entire page each time, as you see.
Also, since you are iterating per each `row` it should be `row.xpath...`, not `rows.xpath` since `rows` is a list of elements while each `row` is an element.
Also, to apply search on a web element according to XPath locator you should use `find_element_by_xpath` method, not `xpath`.

```py
def parse(self, response):
    rows = response.xpath("//tr")
    for row in rows:
        day = row.find_element_by_xpath(".(//tr/td[@class='time']/span)[1]/text()").get()
        time = row.find_element_by_xpath("//.tr/td[@class='time']/span/time/text()").get()

        yield{
            'day': day,
            'time': time,
        }
```

Comment: this helped me a lot, I made a small chang also and with row.xpath I got the results

Comment: Sure. I used selenium method while you used BS method. It's totally OK.

Comment: ohh, glad to hear at least I wasn't that lost :) thank you! you really helped me